# Hazelcast durable message queue

Tags: java, hazelcast

Could you explain me, can I use Hazelcast as broker for durable message queue?
In another words, does Hazelcast guarantee message durability which was putted to queue in case when all cluster nodes is crashed?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

By default Hazelcast works in memory. If you need to persist the data, you can refer to the [Official Docs](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/queue-persistence.html).

If you need persistent messaging queue I would suggest using rabbitmq.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I saw persistence capability and I need to know does Hazelcast close transaction before or after storing message?

Comment: I have found the answer on question above:

"MapStore and QueueStore does not participate in transactions. Hazelcast will suppress exceptions thrown by store in a transaction. Please refer to the XA Transactions section for further information."

In official documentation http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.5/manual/html/transactions.html

Comment: And ironically in the 3.5 docs, the "XA Transactions section" link points to the very same page, but it that page doesn't contain a "XA Transactions section" section :-( The [current](https://docs.hazelcast.com/imdg/4.2/transactions/creating-a-transaction-interface) docs do seem to indicate that transactions are possible also for MapStore and QueueStore  as far as I can tell...